# Fetching data with PDO returns duplicate results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch

I have this code:

```
...
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $this);
$query->execute();
$data = array();
while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
return $data;
```

If I put var_dump here:

```
var_dump($data);
return $data;
```

This is the result:

```
array (size=3)
  0 =>
    object(ChatRoom)[4]
        public 'id' string '3' (length=1)
        ...
  1 =>
    object(ChatRoom)[4]
        public 'id' string '3' (length=1)
        ...
  2 =>
    object(ChatRoom)[4]
        public 'id' string '3' (length=1)
        ...
```

If I put var_dump here:

```
while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
    $data[] = $row;
    var_dump($data);
}
```

This is the result:

```
array (size=1)
  0 =>
    object(ChatRoom)[4]
        public 'id' string '1' (length=1)
        ...
array (size=2)
  0 =>
    object(ChatRoom)[4]
        public 'id' string '2' (length=1)
        ...
  1 =>
    object(ChatRoom)[4]
        public 'id' string '2' (length=1)
        ...
array (size=3)
  0 =>
    object(ChatRoom)[4]
        public 'id' string '3' (length=1)
        ...
  1 =>
    object(ChatRoom)[4]
        public 'id' string '3' (length=1)
        ...
  2 =>
    object(ChatRoom)[4]
        public 'id' string '3' (length=1)
        ...
```

I tried fetchAll but the result its the same. What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a feature you don't need.

```
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $this);
```

remove this line ^

Comment: But I want to return a ChatRoom object not stdObject

Comment: Nope, you don't. You rather need a familiar array, as you surely can manage to handle it

Comment: I can find some other way to manage it but I wanted to do this with this way, for example when I get a list of ChatRoom objects I want to be able to do this: `$chatroom[0]->delete();`. Anyway if I don't find any solution I will use stdObject or associated array

Comment: To populate an object, you have to understand your object structure better.  Way better. Yet until you aren't familiar with it, use conventional array